# Go back to previous page from JS function and retain the field values

Tags: javascript, html

I want to go back to previous JSP page with all its value retained on click of previous button in present JSP page. I am using `history.back()` in JS, but not able to retain the previous field value. How to retain the field values of the previous page?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with JSP/Java and everything to do with HTML/JS.  Get it to work in vanilla HTML/JS and it will work in JSP (ASP, PHP, CGI, a servlet etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using JQuery and a server side session variable to store the values.

1. make sure you have an html id on each form element you need to keep
2. on unload, loop though the elements and send them over to the server to be saved

   ```
    $(window).unload(function() {
       var formValues = {}
       //get the form elements
       elements.each(function() {
           var fieldID = $(this).attr("id");
           formValues[fieldID] = $(this).val();
       }
       json_form = JSON.stringify(formValues);
       $.post("/save_form_values/", {form : json_form} );
   ```
3. I haven't included any code for storing on the server (I found it pretty straightforward with django / python).
4. make another ajax call when you reload the page

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $.get("/get_form_values/", function(data) {
      var formValues = JSON.parse(data);
      $.each(formValues, function(fieldID, value) {
       id_selector = '#' + fieldID;
       $(id_selector).val(value);
      }
    }
   }
   ```